# How to update databricks specific tasks using API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, data-science, databricks, databricks-rest-api

I would like to update databricks multi-task format in job using API endpoint through Python code.I am using this document for reference https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsUpdate

If I want to update notebook_task key for specific task in job. How I can do this through Python code using curl .please advise me

I tried this document https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsUpdate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.